# How would I do these multiple joins as a Django queryset?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I have this query that joins multiple tables together:

```
select 
    p.player_id
    , d.player_data_1
    , l.year
    , l.league
    , s.stat_1
    , l.stat_1_league_average
from 
    stats s
inner join players p on p.player_id = s.player_id
left join player_data d on d.other_player_id = p.other_player_id
left join league_averages as l on l.year = s.year and l.league = s.year
where 
    p.player_id = 123
```

My models look like this:

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    player_id = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    stat_1 = models.IntegerField()
    year = models.IntegerField()
    league = models.IntegerField()


class Player(models.Model):
    player_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    other_player_id = models.ForeignKey(PlayerData)

class PlayerData(models.Model):
    other_player_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    player_data_1 = models.TextField()

class LeagueAverages(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    league = models.IntegerField()
    stat_1_league_average = models.DecimalField()
```

I can do something like this:

```
Stats.objects.filter(player_id=123).select_related('player')
```

to do the first join. For the second join, I tried:

```
Stats.objects.filter(player_id=123).select_related('player').select_related('player_data')
```

but I got this error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'player_data'. Choices are: player

How would I do the third join considering that `year` and `league` aren't foreign keys in any of the tables? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [**select_related(*fields)**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, [...]

According to the django documentation  `select_related` follows foreign-key relationships. `player_data` is neighter a foreign key, nor even an field of `Stats`. If you'd want to **INNER join** `PlayerData` and `Player` you could follow its foreign-keys. In your case use the 
[double-underscore](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to get to `PlayerData`:

```
Stats.objects.all()
    .select_related('player_id')
    .select_related('player_id__other_player_id')
```

As for joining `LeagueAverages`: There is not a way to join models without an appropriate foreign key, but to use raw sql. Have a look at a related question: [Django JOIN query without foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16669422/3384932). By using `.raw()`, your **LEFT join** (which by the way is also not that easy without using raw: [Django Custom Left Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820170/django-custom-left-outer-join)) could also be taken care of.

Quick notes about your models:

1. Each model by default has an automatically incrementing primary key that can be accessed via `.id` or `.pk`. So there is no need to add for example `player_id`
2. A `models.ForeignKey` field references an object not it's id. Therefore it's more intuitive to rename for example `player_id` to `player`. If you name your field `player` django allows you automatically to access it's id via `player_id`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The double-underscore for `PlayerData` worked. Too bad about my third join. As for the auto incrementing primary key, I'm not using that because the data in these tables is from a third-party source.

Comment: Glad i could help a little. You could still set the id manually at creation, even though it is auto-incrementing. But if you choose to rename it on purpose, I don't think there is a problem with that. I only think it would be more consistent in this particular case.