# Django: use select_related / prefetch_related for 3 models in one query

Tags: django, django-models, optimization, prefetch

I have few Django models:
`Domains`, `Kpis`, `Tests`, `TestsAndKpis`

`TestsAndKpis` is many-to-many model with `test_id` and `kpi_id` as keys.  `Kpis` model has a ForiegnKey of `domain_id`.

I want to efficiently get data from my DB (i use MySQL), meaning to have as less DB queries as possible.

Currently, to get what i need i run this

```
items = [{'kpi_type': t_k.type,
  'kpi_name': t_k.kpi_id.name,
  'kpi_display_name': t_k.kpi_id.display_name,
  'domain_display_name':t_k.kpi_id.domain_id.display_name}
   for t_k in TestsAndKpis.objects.filter(test_id=test_id).select_related('kpi_id')]
```

Which results my application to run LOTS of redundant queries [like `SELECT ... FROM domains WHERE domains.id = 6` [total of 25 queries]

When i remove the 'domain_display_name' key that extract from domains table:

```
items = [{'kpi_type': t_k.type,
  'kpi_name': t_k.kpi_id.name,
  'kpi_display_name': t_k.kpi_id.display_name
   for t_k in TestsAndKpis.objects.filter(test_id=test_id).select_related('kpi_id')]
```

The application runs only 15 queries in total and returns MUCH faster.

My question: How can i extract the data efficiently, and avoid the redundant 10 queries?
I tried to use chained `select_related`/`prefetch_related` but it did not work out for me.

Comment: try using chained prefetch related
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50047815/how-would-i-do-these-multiple-joins-as-a-django-queryset/50051751#50051751

Comment: Thanks @Kallie. It solved my problem. i applied this: `for t_k in TestsAndKpis.objects.filter(test_id=test_id).select_related('kpi_id').select_related('kpi_id__domain_id')]` and it reduced the number of queries to 15 again.